Which statistical model will be best for this data?
I'm trying to identify the relationship between the dependent variable and the independent variables. I've utilized linear regression, but I'm not sure if it's suitable given the distribution of my data. Could you please advise me on how to effectively explain the variance in the data?

I present here just several of my vars but the rest are distributed pretty much the same
My model:
model1 <- lmer(dep_var ~ var1 + var2 + var3 + var4 + var5 + var6 + var7 + var8 + var9 + var10 +
                var11 + var12 + var13 + var14 + var15 + var16 + var17 + var18 + var19 + var20 +
                (1|Gene) + (1|ID) + (1|Status), data = data11)

summary of it:
Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance  Std.Dev.
 ID       (Intercept) 3.605e-04 0.018988
 Gene     (Intercept) 4.488e-02 0.211848
 Status   (Intercept) 2.915e-05 0.005399
 Residual             1.656e-02 0.128704
Number of obs: 209542, groups:  ID, 1088; Gene, 961; Status, 3

Fixed effects:
              Estimate Std. Error         df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  1.609e-01  9.418e-03  1.419e+02  17.080  < 2e-16 ***
var1         1.217e-03  5.367e-04  8.568e+02   2.267 0.023628 *  
var2         1.005e-04  6.023e-04  8.360e+02   0.167 0.867529    
var3         1.320e-03  5.431e-04  8.507e+02   2.430 0.015297 *  
var4        -4.154e-04  1.007e-03  8.838e+02  -0.413 0.680029    
var5         1.130e-03  5.879e-04  8.398e+02   1.921 0.055036 .  
var6         9.305e-04  5.881e-04  8.517e+02   1.582 0.113985    
var7        -9.708e-04  7.902e-04  8.570e+02  -1.229 0.219582    
var8         1.879e-03  6.657e-04  8.736e+02   2.822 0.004875 ** 
var9        -8.587e-04  6.772e-04  8.647e+02  -1.268 0.205152    
var10       -4.270e-04  7.362e-04  8.665e+02  -0.580 0.562010    
var11        4.382e-04  6.182e-04  8.521e+02   0.709 0.478555    
var12        1.847e-04  5.788e-04  8.600e+02   0.319 0.749717    
var13        3.404e-04  7.175e-04  8.451e+02   0.474 0.635299    
var14       -6.316e-04  5.982e-04  8.495e+02  -1.056 0.291350    
var15       -6.653e-04  6.163e-04  8.438e+02  -1.080 0.280655    
var16        3.811e-04  6.196e-04  8.500e+02   0.615 0.538629    
var17        6.515e-04  6.586e-04  8.470e+02   0.989 0.322847    
var18        7.140e-04  8.014e-04  8.486e+02   0.891 0.373221    
var19       -2.639e-03  7.015e-04  8.524e+02  -3.761 0.000181 ***
var20       -3.904e-04  6.714e-04  8.465e+02  -0.582 0.561052    

and the summary of residuals:
   Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
-7.33078 -0.32714 -0.07541  0.00000  0.21434  7.79032

I will share any additional information if needed.

What do the residuals from the linear regression look like? How about other diagnostics?

Showing univariate statistics is nice for context but gives virtually no information about the relationships among the variables.  You therefore are basically asking us to write a textbook on multiple regression for you.  Since that's been done many times, and none of them would fit into the space we have, please provide more specifics and craft a narrower subquestion.

It looks like your dependent variable is a proportion of some kind, limited to values in the closed interval [0,1]. That's probably not suitable for ordinary linear regression. Please edit the question to say more about the nature of the dependent variable and how its values are obtained. That will at least let someone  point you to the type of multiple regression that you should investigate. Please edit the question to provide more information, as comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted.

Just edited the question. @EdM

@PeterFlom what do you think now?

Better, but we still don't know what the dependent variable represents, how it's measured, and why it's limited to [0,1]. I'd worry about a situation where a quarter of your residuals are below -.32 while the mean dependent-variable value seems to be about 0.1 and no values are below 0. Also, it's not clear what Status represents; with only 3 levels I think that many would treat that as a fixed-effect predictor rather than as a random effect. I (and I suspect @PeterFlom) would like to see diagnostic plots incorporating residuals, not just their overall distribution.

The choice of statistical model should depend on the nature of the real-world data generating system more than it does on the observed properties of the data that is observed. That means that you know more than the statistical wizards you have asked.

That helps a bit, but see the other comments for more questions.  Also, in general, naming variables var1 var2 etc. isn't a great idea. It tells your readers nothing and, if you come back to this a year later, even you might not know.

A statistical model should follow theoretical ideas about the data. How does it arrises and what does it represent. What can we think about the peaks at 0 and 1? What mechanism causes the bulge in between?

When you edit the question to provide more information about the dependent variable, you might also say more about the nature of the predictor variables. From the plots it seems that they can only take integer values between 1 and 5. Is that correct, or have they already been binned into those 5 levels from continuous values? Note that your model, with only 1 coefficient per predictor, implicitly assumes that each of those variables is linearly associated, in that 1-5 scale, with outcome. Do you think that's a reasonable assumption?
